# Should we check NULL when cast IClass to Class?

Tags: c#

Question 1> Should I check NULL in the following case?

```
public interface INewClass {}
public class NewClass : INewClass {}

public void FunMeA(INewClass obj)
{
    NewClass n = (NewClass) obj;
    ... // Should I check (n == null) here?
    // call methods defined inside INewClass (updated from NewClass to INewClass)
    ...
}

A concrete example,

public void FunMeB(IAsyncResult itfAR)
{
    AsyncResult ar = (AsyncResult) itfAR;
    ... // Should I check (ar == null) here?
    // access ar.AsyncDelegate
    ...
}
```

Question 2> I just start to transfer to C# from C++.
When coding in C++, I know when the checking should be done.
However, I am totally lost in the C# world. So the question is: is there
a general rule that can tell me when I MUST check for NULL?

Thank you

Comment: If the methods are defined on the INewClass interface, why are you casting at all?

Comment: Just check if the object is NULL before using the function.  The ideal situation is by the time you use the method, the object cannot be null, because its required for your program to function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When doing this:

```
NewClass n = (NewClass) obj;
```

There is no point, because if it doesn't cast it will throw an invalid cast exception.

If you have any doubts as to whether or not you can actually cast it, you want to do:

```
NewClass n = obj as NewClass;
```

then

```
if(n != null) ...
```

The cast you are doing is called a direct cast, where the system will assume that it can be made.  the `n = obj as NewClass` is called an indirect cast and is for those scenarios where you want to tell the program "Hey I think this will work, but if not don't flip out and throw an exception...I'll deal with it if it doesn't work."

Using `is` vs `as` in casting.

Depending on which scenario you want one will be better than the other.  Technically from a performance perspective `as` is preferred.  .Net will use atomically attempt to cast to the desired type and return null if it's not, where with `is` it will have to walk the inheritance tree twice to see if it matches that type and then cast it.  So in most cases if you want to see if you want to cast and use that type it's better to:

```
var obj = o as type
if (obj != null)
```

as opposed to

```
if(o is type)
{
   var obj = (type); 
}
```

Comment: -1: That last paragraph doesn't make a lot of sense.  How do you suppose .NET determines whether a cast is legal with the `as` keyword or the `(SomeType)variable` syntax?  It obviously has to look at the inheritance tree.  The documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) says that the as expression is equivalent to `expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null` except that the expression is evaluated only once.  Also, try looking at the IL.  I compiled the expression `return (value as TOut) != null;` and Reflector disassembled it as `return (value is TOut);`

Comment: ... continued: But the IL for the `as` operator has 12 instructions as opposed to 8 for the `is` operator.

Comment: You're right that didn't make a whole lot os sense. I've fixed it.

Comment: +1 - -1 = +2 ... How's that for a confusing double negative expression!

Answer (score 5):

If the cast fails, your code will throw an exception.

Use the [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator to see if a cast will work, and [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) to cast (which will not throw and return a null if the cast fails).

So:

```
if(obj is NewClass)
{
  //Yay, can cast!
}
```

Or:

```
NewClass nc = obj as NewClass;
if(nc != null)
{
  //Yay!
}
```

Comment: But don't use 'is' and 'as' together.  If you want to handle the possibility that the cast is invalid, use 'as' with a null check.

Comment: Of course. My point is that 'if (x is SomeType) { var y = x as SomeType; ... }' is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for null then you should do

```
NewClass n = obj as NewClass ;
if (n != null)
{

...

}
```

But in general you could check for null if that means something to in the context and you can take alternative actions. In most cased, you should just let it throw NullReferenceException rather than swallowing it so you can identify the cause of the null reference faster.

Comment: This assignment will not throw a NullReferenceException if obj is null: `NewClass n = (NewClass)obj;`

Comment: @phoog What I meant to say was that, you should check for null only if you exactly know why it's null and have means to handle the situation. Some people check for null on anything and everything they work with and do nothing in the else part. It results in no runtime null pointer exception but when something is wrong, it's hard to figure out what's wrong. It's best to so a direct cast rather than safe cast in most situations.

Comment: Agreed.  It is very frustrating when programs fail silently.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `NewClass n = (NewClass)obj` you'll get an exception thrown if it doesn't cast properly.

If you want there to be a possibility of it being null, without throwing an exception, you'd want to do `NewClass n = obj as NewClass;` and then check if `n` is null.

You can check if a cast is going to work before hand, by using the `is` operator.
`if(obj is NewClass)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can cast a null reference.  Try it, you'll like it.

Answer (score 2):

If the parameter is required, you should always check for `null` and throw an `ArgumentException` or `ArugmentNullException`.

The best way for this parameter check here is:

```
AsyncResult ar = itfAR as AsyncResult;
if(ar == null)
{
    // even better: Use a resource here
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Parameter itfAR must not be null and must be of type AsyncResult"); 
}
```

Comment: @q0987 There is also an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, but this wouldn't make any sense here of course

Comment: This could cause a misleading exception.  For example, if itfAR is of a type that implements IAsyncResult but does not inherit from AsyncResult, you will throw an ArgumentNullException even if the argument was not null.  Confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to check to for null before the cast.  E.g.

```
if (obj == null) 
{
  throw new ArgumentNullException("obj", "The argument must has a value specified");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are mixing up to issues.

1. You should always validate arguments to a publicly exposed method. Therefore you sould first do:

   public WhateEverMethod(IElement iElement)
   {
        if (iElement == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(...);
        }
   }
2. Once you have validated that element is not null you check if you can perform the cast. You can go two ways essentially:

   Element element = iElement as Element;

   if (element == null) //cast failed
   {
      throw new InvalidCastException(...);
   }

or

```
if (!(iElement is Element))
{
    throw new InvalidCastException(...);
}

Element element = (Element)iElement;
```

Comment: `Element element = (Element)(new Object());` throws an `InvalidCastException` anyway, so why check and throw it in the first place!?

Comment: I second Simon's point.  If the cast being invalid is an exceptional condition, there's no point in throwing an invalid cast exception yourself.  However, when I do this, I generally add a comment so somebody else won't think I overlooked the possibility of an invalid cast and change my code: `var theString = (string)obj; // throws an exception if obj is not a string`

Comment: @Simon: True, my bad. I wasn't thinking clearly. The point I wanted to get through though is that I would differentiate between ArgumentNull and InvalidCast. But obviously yes, the cast check is completely unnecessary.